# how to position logo half way over div below it no matter what screen size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I need to position a logo halfway over the div below it like in the image below and I cannot seem to get it perfect.  It needs to be halfway over no matter what the screen size or browser size, even during adjusting of browser size.

I am using positioning like this

```
.site-icon {
  width: 15%;
  top: 6%;
  right: 11.9%;
}
```

HTML for the section

```
<div class="container-fluid page-container-2">
  <h1 class="page-title-2 small-header">
   <a href="/">SITE TITLE</a>
  </h1>

  <!-- This is the icon -->
  <a href="/"><img class="site-icon" src="/resources/img/icon.png" alt="site_title"/></a>

  <!-- this is the div holding the banner image -->
  <div class="col-xs-12 banner-image-container-2 no-pad" style="background: url({% resource banner_image['path'] %}) no-repeat center center;background-size:cover;"></div>

.... rest of the page ....
```

But it fails when the browser is shrunk down vertically or horizontally and I just cannot figure out how to achieve this with css?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for providing your CSS, but can you please provide the relevant HTML as well? It's almost impossible to answer this question without it. It would help if you could update your question to list all **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your HTML is generated server-side, please post the **output**. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, when I wrote my answer, you didn't have any HTML code in your question ,so I came up with my own - but that also should be understandable as an answer for your question... (won't change that anymore now)

The most important thing is to have a combination of `position: relative` (for the parent) and `position absoute (for the child element), plus width, height and position settings especially for the child. Take a look at the settings in the snippet below.

```css
.x {
  position: relative;
  top: 70px;
  height: 160px;
  background: #fa0;
}

.site-icon {
  position: absolute;
  width: 15%;
  height: 50%;
  top: 0;
  right: 12%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: #0fa;
}
```

```html
<div class="x">
  <div class="site-icon"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was able to fit that to it and it worked, saved me a ton of time, thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the positioning that way, what you can do is to have one `absolute` container and then position the logo this way. This technique will not be depending on the size of the logo:

```css
.header {position: relative; margin: 100px 0 0;}
.logo-container {position: absolute; right: 0;}
.logo {position: absolute; right: 0; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);}
.container {background-color: #eef; border: 1px solid #ccf; margin-bottom: 25px; padding-top: 50px;}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo-container">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/100x75?text=Logo" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p>Rest of Page. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit ducimus, porro atque laboriosam. Architecto similique, explicabo aut iste ipsam magnam labore qui omnis eius vitae, nihil distinctio, molestias dolore quisquam!</p>
</div>

<div class="header">
  <div class="logo-container">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/100?text=Logo" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p>Rest of Page. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam nesciunt velit nam sapiente, sint autem voluptas a laborum ad, molestias delectus nobis repellendus assumenda mollitia harum id nisi expedita ut.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.header {
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom:300px;
}

.icone {
    width: 15%;
    top: -35%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 40%;
    right: 11.9%;
    background-color: #d9eff4;
    min-width: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
}.header-container {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f6a68a;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 70%;
    width: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 990px) {
    .icone {
    width: 40%;
    height: 40%;}

}
@media only screen and (max-width:440px) {
    .icone {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;}

}
@media only screen and (max-width:320px) {
    .icone {
    width: 70%;
    height: 40%;}

}
```

```html
<div class="header">
<div class="header-container">
<div class="icone"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Try this